# сортировка по алфавиту массива

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Генерирую массив строк, и задача их отсортировать по алфавиту. Пытаюсь передать в функцию массив, но не пойму как это правильно сделать

UPD  передать удалось, но вопрос сортировки остался

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

int i;
int j;
int string_count = 10;

void sort(char massive[][11]){
    for (j = 0; j<string_count;j++){
        for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            //strcpy(massive[j][i],massive[j+1][i]);
        }  
        std::cout << "sorted " << massive[j] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    char symbols[27]  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char massive[string_count][11] = {0};
    int random;
    for (j = 0; j<string_count;j++){
        for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            random = rand()%(26);
            massive[j][i] = symbols[random];
        }  
        std::cout << "unsorted " << massive[j] << std::endl;
        
    }

    sort(massive);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Используйте вектор строк и передавайте его по ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас непонятно С или С++. Если С++, то надо использовать массив строк. Уж очень двумерный массив не подходит для простой и легкой сортировки - в нем надо все время обменять не указатели, а прямо строки. Получается очень неприятное и неопрятное решение.

```
const int string_count = 10;

void sort(char massive[][11]) {
    char tmp[11];
    for (int j = 0; j < string_count; j++) {
        for (int i = string_count - 1; i > j; i--) {
            if (strcmp(massive[i - 1], massive[i]) > 0) {
                strcpy(tmp, massive[i]);
                strcpy(massive[i], massive[i - 1]);
                strcpy(massive[i - 1], tmp);
                }
            }
        std::cout << "sorted " << massive[j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

int main() {
    char symbols[27]  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char massive[string_count][11] = {0};
    for (int j = 0; j < string_count; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            massive[j][i] = symbols[rand() % 26];
            }
        std::cout << "unsorted " << massive[j] << std::endl;
        }
    sort(massive);
    }
```

Вот то же самое с массивом строк:

```
const int string_count = 10;

int main() {
    char symbols[27]  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    std::string massive[string_count];

    for (int j = 0; j < string_count; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            massive[j] += symbols[rand() % 26];
            }

        std::cout << "unsorted " << massive[j] << std::endl;
        }

    std::sort(massive, massive + string_count);

    for (int j = 0; j < string_count; j++) {
        std::cout << "sorted " << massive[j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
```